# Call Camera from another activity and get the image location in parent activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent, onactivityresult

I have a class which contains the method to call the camera intent then save the picture and send the image location to the called activity. But there is an exception whenever I click on the camera icon.

```
public String onCaptureImageResult() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createimage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));


        }

    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

}




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && data != null) {

        //String g = compressImage(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        String mCurrentPhotoPath = f.getAbsolutePath();
        g = compressImage(mCurrentPhotoPath);


    }
```

}

Now i need the value g in the parent activity. Exception i got is given below.

```
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.snatarajan.checkcompress, PID: 26553
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:861)
        at com.example.snatarajan.checkcompress.work.onCaptureImageResult(work.java:51)
        at com.example.snatarajan.checkcompress.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:254)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at                                                    
       06-30 15:16:47.447    844-31592/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/2 from pid=555, uid=1000 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:539)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:452)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:443)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openFile(ContentProvider.java:340)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:240)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

From Activity 1 i called like

```
 w.onCaptureImageResult();
```

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace

Comment: @Laser - Attached complete trace

Comment: So your app  does not even open up the camera and why do you call startActivityForResult when createImageFile fails

Comment: @Laser - yes it doesnt open camera, to create a image name for further process..

Comment: Try this in your manifest. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> if you 're saving the file to sdcard

Comment: @Laser it is there already

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116073/discussion-between-laser-and-user2269164).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your manifest:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

And if your device is Marshmallow,then you need to give runtime permissions for using camera.

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Which android version are you using?Marshmallow?